# How to convert local storage image path into network image url in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I have a local storage image path like:

/Users/newuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D7515987-8FDF-47A7-A6E1-A210739CB2A5/data/Containers/Data/Application/DC529635-F924-40DF-B530-85710D23A8D0/Library/Application Support/localstorage_images/2022-05-04/12:50:41.png

I have display this image using

image: FileImage(
url),
fit: BoxFit.cover,
),

here var url contains the local storage image path /Users/newuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D7515987-8FDF-47A7-A6E1-A210739CB2A5/data/Containers/Data/Application/DC529635-F924-40DF-B530-85710D23A8D0/Library/Application Support/localstorage_images/2022-05-04/12:50:41.png in File data type

I want to pass this var url in like below:

image: NetworkImage(
url),
fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
my problem was how to convert FileImage type to NetworkImage type because my other images are NetworkImage type it is possible to convert FileImage into Network image in flutter

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the url and see if the the URL is of local image of network image and based on that show the dedicated widget

Comment: i need to add this local image path to the carousel slider my carousel slider already contains network images i want to add this local image into that image list that is possible?

Comment: yes, it's possible

Comment: could you help me to solve this issue? how could we do that

Comment: could you upload any sample @nitishk72